# Do I have to define var as Decimal?

Tags: python, django

I know, `platform_fee_percentage` will always be a `Decimal` (called from the database). Is it necessary that I define `Decimal` explicitly, or will Python always give it the type `Decimal`? If not, the function quantize would fail.

```
def calculate_application_fee(platform_fee_percentage, total_gross):
    calculate_application_fee = Decimal(platform_fee_percentage * total_gross)
    application_fee = quantize(calculate_application_fee, '1')
    return application_fee
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import Decimal (`from decimal import Decimal`) so Python knows what you mean.

`quantize` is a method of a `Decimal` object, so to round to units you would call it like this:

```
Decimal('12.3456').quantize(Decimal('1'))
```

or in your example:

```
calculate_application_fee.quantize(Decimal('1'))
```

See the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) for more info